# ML wrong prediction on Japan Crossword puzzle

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I’m trying to study machine learning in hands-on way. I found exercise for myself to create neural network that solves “Japan crosswords” for fixed size images (128*128).

Very simple example (4*4) demonstrates the conception: black & white picture encoded by top and left matrices. Number in matrix means continues length of black line. Easy to prove left and top matrix have dimension at max (N*(N/2)) and ((N/2)*N) correspondingly.

[image]

I have a python generator that creates random b&w images and 2 reduced matrices. Top and left matrices are fed as input (left is transposed to match top) and b&w as an expected output. Input is treated as 3-dim (128 * 64 * 2) where 2 – is top and left correspondingly. 
Following is my current topology that try to build function (128 * 64 * 2) -> (128, 128, 1)

> Model: "model"
>
> ---
>
> Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
>
> ---
>
> ---
>
> interlaced_reduce (InputLaye [(None, 128, 64, 2)]      0
>
> ---
>
> small_conv (Conv2D)          (None, 128, 64, 32)       288
>
> ---
>
> leaky_re_lu (LeakyReLU)      (None, 128, 64, 32)       0
>
> ---
>
> medium_conv (Conv2D)         (None, 128, 64, 64)       8256
>
> ---
>
> leaky_re_lu_1 (LeakyReLU)    (None, 128, 64, 64)       0
>
> ---
>
> large_conv (Conv2D)          (None, 128, 64, 128)      32896
>
> ---
>
> leaky_re_lu_2 (LeakyReLU)    (None, 128, 64, 128)      0
>
> ---
>
> up_sampling2d (UpSampling2D) (None, 128, 128, 128)     0
>
> ---
>
> dropout (Dropout)            (None, 128, 128, 128)     0
>
> ---
>
> dense (Dense)                (None, 128, 128, 1)       129
>
> ---
>
> ---
>
> Total params: 41,569
>   Trainable params: 41,569
>   Non-trainable params: 0
>
> ---

After train on 50 images I got the following statistic (please note, I tried to normalize input matrices to [0,1] without any success, current statistic demonstrate non-normalized case) :

> ... 
>   Epoch 50/50 2/2 [==============================] - 1s 687ms/step -loss: 18427.2871 - mae: 124.9277

Then prediction produces following:

[image]

You can see left – expected random image and right – result of prediction. In prediction I intentionally use grey-scaled image to understand how close my result to target. But as you can see – the prediction is far from expected and is close to source form of top/left reduce matrices.
So my questions:

1) What layers I’m missing?

2) What should be improved in existing topology?

p.s. this is [cross post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/468598) from Cross Validated Stackexchange, because nobody even viewed question that site

Comment: Was this the first model you tried? Have you explored simpler models without a convolution layer such as a multilayer perceptron? My gut feeling is that a convolution layer localises the information in the input, but for this problem a global context is helpful

Comment: @DesmondCheong - that was core of my question, what should I use to build relevant pipeline. I started with convolution just because there is no general guidance what NN suitable in particular cases. Instead I see like: "to process any image you need Conv2D layer"

Comment: It's true that convolution layers are often used to process images because they help build up a hierarchical understanding of the image that is scale/shift/rotation invariant etc. But an 'image' is just a representation. If we consider the problem you're solving, it's just as valid to think of the input as two matrices of numbers, and the output is a matrix of 1s and 0s that correspond to 'black' and 'white'.

Comment: In general a simple NN (and one that works surprisingly well lots of the time) is an [MLP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilayer_perceptron). You could try a model with 1. a Flatten layer that takes in your two reduced matrices as inputs and flattens them, 2. a hidden dense layer, maybe with something like 128 nodes and a relu activation (you can experiment with this), 3. an output dense layer with 16384 nodes (with step actiation maybe) which you then reshape and reformat into your desired image. Of course, no guarantees that this model would work well, but it's a good first model to try.

Comment: @DesmondCheong - can you please create answer from your last comment, so I can rate it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The model you build is a conventional model (seen by the use of Conv2D). This layer are good in analyzing something given its neighbors. Making them very powerful for image classification or segmentation.

In your case the result of a pixels is depending on the whole line and column.

Neural networks seems to be unsuited for your problem, but if you want to continue look in to replacing conv layers with Conv(1xN) and Conv(Nx1). It will still be very hard to make it work.

The hard way: These puzzle exist out of a strong recurrent process. Each step the correct spots get filled int with a zero or one. Based on those the next get filled in. So a recurrent neural network would make most sense to me. Where the convolution is used to have the prediction of the neighbors influence its current prediction

Comment: Ok, so Conv2D is not working, then what is your recommendation?

Comment: How set are you on using neural networks? DNN are good for very noisy data with hard to define rule, but with a logic puzzle you have the opposite

Comment: Well, I'm serious about learning NN in a hard way. Because I have rather good understanding how Japan Crossword can be solved with help of Z3 library or using recursion with general purpose languages.

Comment: Well the hard way it is. These puzzle exist out of a strong recurrent process. Each step the correct spots get filled int with a zero or one. Based on those the next get filled in. So a recurrent neural network would make most sense to me. Where the convolution is used to have the prediction of the neighbors influence its current prediction

Comment: can you please edit your answer according to the last comment, so I can rate it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So it's hard to say what model would work best without training and testing the actual model, but from the results you've gotten so far here's a few options you could try.

**Try adding a fully connected hidden layer**

From the model you posted, it seems that you have a few convolution layers, followed by an up-sampling and dropout layer, and finally a single dense layer for your output nodes. Potentially, adding additional dense layers (for e.g. 128 or more or less nodes) before your final output layer might help. While the multiple convolution layers help the neural net to build up a sort of hierarchical understanding of the image, the hypothesis class might not be complex enough. Adding one or more dense layers might help with this.

**Try using a multilayer perceptron**

Convolution layers are often used to process images because they help build up a hierarchical understanding of the image that is somewhat scale/shift/rotation invariant. However, considering the problem that you're solving, a global understanding of the input might be more beneficial than identifying shift-invariant features.

As such, one possible option would be to remove the convolution layers and to use a multilayer perceptron ([MLP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilayer_perceptron)).

Let us think of the input as two matrices of numbers, and the output is a matrix of 1s and 0s that correspond to 'black' and 'white'. You could then try a model with the following layers:

1. A Flatten layer that takes in your two reduced matrices as inputs and flattens 
   them
2. A hidden dense layer, maybe with something like 128 nodes and relu activation. You should experiment with the number of layers, nodes, and activation.
3. An output dense layer with 16384 (128x128) nodes. You could apply a softmax activation to this layer which could help the optimiser during the training process. Then, when creating your final image, set values < 0.5 to 0 and values >= 0.5 to 1, and reshape and reformat the matrix into a square image.

Of course, no guarantees that an MLP would work well, but if often does especially when given sufficient amounts of data (perhaps in the 1000s or more number of training examples).

**Try using a deterministic algorithm**

Looking at the structure of this problem, it seems that it could be solved more appropriately with a deterministic algorithm, which would fall under more the branch of traditional artificial intelligence rather than deep learning. This is also another potential route to explore.

Comment: About deterministic algorithm - you absolutely right, I've already put answer to Tom Nijhof: "I have good understanding how Japan Crossword can be solved with help of Z3 library or using recursion with general purpose language", but using NN for me is a good way to learn this domain